# transfer Image via BLUETOOTH from hardware device to Android device in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, arrays, data-transfer

I am working on a Bluetooth application in which I have created connection between Android Device and an hardware device.

I am successful in **SENDING AND ACCEPTING TEXT DATA** from & to the hardware device.

I am getting problem in IMAGE TRANSFER from hardware device to Android Device.

I am using below code to CREATE BITMAP from BYTE ARRAY and SAVE it to SDCard:

```
  public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice device) {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "connected");

        // Cancel the thread that completed the connection
        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }

        // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
        mConnectedThread.start();

        //CREATE IMAGE FILE
        File empowered=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "ImageFile.jpeg");

        if (empowered.exists()) {
            empowered.delete();
        }

        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(empowered.getPath());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {

            //fos.write(buffer);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(buffer , 0, buffer.length);

            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);


        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        setState(STATE_CONNECTED);
    }
```

**RECEIVING CODE:**

```
public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");

        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        //while (true) {

        try {
            // Read from the InputStream
            bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
            if (bytes != -1) {
                //ensure DATAMAXSIZE Byte is read.
                int byteNo2 = bytes;
                int bufferSize = 7340;
                while(byteNo2 != bufferSize){
                    bufferSize = bufferSize - byteNo2;
                    byteNo2 = mmInStream.read(buffer,bytes,bufferSize);
                    if(byteNo2 == -1){
                        break;
                    }
                    bytes = bytes+byteNo2;
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
        testModeOnScreen.sendMailTest("emailAddress","Received bytes"+e.toString(),"IOEXCEPTION");
        connectionLost();
        //break;
    }
}
```

Comment: this type of response was not expected...not a single suggestion from anyone.

Comment: Try adding description of the issue you are encountering with the binary files. Not everyone has time to create test project and test your code just to see how the issue manifests itself.

Comment: The code is not showing any exception,It is creating a .jpeg file but i am not able to see that file or it shows invalid file

Comment: Have you tried writing received file to a local storage and checking if that file matches the original one? Straight comparison should show you what is wrong/missing/etc in the received image.

Comment: Yes ofcourse I have written the code to write received file in local storage but the problem is , It is not writing the data in file

Comment: So what happens when you debug? Do you receive any binary data at all? You need to find out which part of your code breaks: is it receiving part, decoding, writing to a local storage? By the way, why don't you just sent image in a raw binary format without (de)coding?

Comment: Yes the app is receiving binary data but i don't know when the blocking read call is finished .As i need to rearrange the binary data and create image from it.

Comment: Could you successfully create the image ?? @Sam-In-TechValens